# Was the woman not further charged with adultery after having been proved to be impure in Number 5:27?

Tags: numbers, moses, purity-laws

Numbers 5:27 NIV

. ***27 If she has made herself impure and been unfaithful to her husband***, this will be the result: When she is made to drink the water that brings a curse and causes bitter suffering, it will enter her, her abdomen will swell and her womb will miscarry, and she will become a curse.

After having been proved that the woman had committed adultery there seems to be no other charges laid against her.

Was the woman not further charged with adultery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adulterous acts are mentioned in all 5 books of the Pentateuch. It was an important legal matter.

Genesis 12:19

> Why did you say, 'She is my sister,' so that I took her to be my wife? Now then, here is your wife. Take her and go!"

Exodus 20:14

> You shall not commit adultery.

Leviticus 18:20

> You must not lie carnally with your neighbor's wife and thus defile yourself with her.

Deuteronomy 5:18

> You shall not commit adultery.

Deuteronomy 22:22

> If a man is found lying with another man's wife, both the man who slept with her and the woman must **die**. You must purge the evil from Israel.

In particular, the OP focus on the book of Numbers.

Numbers 5:

> 27 If she has made herself impure and been unfaithful to her husband, this will be the result: When she is made to drink the water that brings a curse and causes bitter suffering, it will enter her, her abdomen will swell and her womb will miscarry, and she will become a curse.

Interestingly, the word "adultery" does not even appear in the Book of Numbers.

> 29 “ ‘This, then, is the **law of jealousy** when a woman goes astray and makes herself impure while married to her husband, 30or when feelings of jealousy come over a man because he suspects his wife. The priest is to have her stand before the Lord and is to apply this entire law to her.  31The husband will be innocent of any wrongdoing, but the woman will bear the consequences of her sin.’ ”

More precisely, the Book of Numbers dealt with the suspicious adulterous act as a separate law: the law of jealousy.

OP wrote: having been proved that the woman had committed adultery

Not exactly. The law only justified the husband's jealousy. If the husband wished to pursue further charges,
Deuteronomy 17:6 applied:

> On the testimony of two or three witnesses a person is to be put to death, but no one is to be put to death on the testimony of only one witness.

Was the woman not further charged with adultery after having been proved to be impure in Number 5:27?

That's up to the husband but he would need witnesses which the law of jealousy did not require. The law of jealousy was meant to be a deterrence for the wife for thinking to commit adultery. Good question.

Comment: ,thank you for a good answer

Comment: Thanks for the question. It made me think.